# Word Frequency HW

Tags: python, python-3.x

Write a program that asks a user for a file name, then reads in the file. The program should then determine how frequently each word in the file is used. The words should be counted regardless of case, for example Spam and spam would both be counted as the same word. You should disregard punctuation. The program should then output the the words and how frequently each word is used. The output should be sorted by the most frequent word to the least frequent word.

Only problem I am having is getting the code to count "The" and "the" as the same thing. The code counts them as different words.

```
userinput = input("Enter a file to open:")
if len(userinput) < 1 : userinput = 'ran.txt'
f = open(userinput)
di = dict()
for lin in f:
    lin = lin.rstrip()
    wds = lin.split()
    for w in wds:
        di[w] = di.get(w,0) + 1
    lst = list()
    for k,v in di.items():
       newtup = (v, k)
       lst.append(newtup)
lst = sorted(lst, reverse=True)
print(lst)
```

Need to count "the" and "The" as on single word.

Comment: Make the words lower case before adding them (and use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)).

Comment: Check my answer below and see if it helps you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We start by getting the words in a list, updating the list so that all words are in lowercase. You can disregard punctuation by replacing them from the string with an empty character

```
punctuations = '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
s = "I want to count how many Words are there.i Want to Count how Many words are There"

for punc in punctuations:
    s = s.replace(punc,' ')

words = s.split(' ')
words = [word.lower() for word in words]
```

We then iterate through the list, and update a frequency map.

```
freq = {}

for word in words:
    if word in freq:
        freq[word] += 1
    else:
        freq[word] = 1
print(freq)
#{'i': 2, 'want': 2, 'to': 2, 'count': 2, 'how': 2, 'many': 2, 
#'words': 2, 'are': #2, 'there': 2}
```

Comment: This implementation doesn't support punctuation.

Comment: From the post: "You should disregard punctuation" - I think that means stripping punctuation. For example in "Once upon a time, there was...", "time" should be extracted without the comma.

Comment: Thanks! All I was missing was words = [word.lower() for word in words]

Answer (score 1):

You can use counter and re like this,

```
from collections import Counter
import re

sentence = 'Egg ? egg Bird, Goat  afterDoubleSpace\nnewline'

# some punctuations (you can add more here)
punctuationsToBeremoved = ",|\n|\?" 

#to make all of them in lower case
sentence = sentence.lower() 

#to clean up the punctuations
sentence = re.sub(punctuationsToBeremoved, " ", sentence) 

# getting the word list
words = sentence.split()

# printing the frequency of each word
print(Counter(words))
```